# header anchor tag does not redirect correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a simple one page app.
In the header, I have redirects to different parts of the website.
for some mysterious reason, the redirects for 'features' is not working all the way.
the redirect scrolls the user to somesort of half point. so a bit of the element is being cut off

here is the code::
https://codesandbox.io/s/bosky-active-ow4qs7

here is the features component:
https://codesandbox.io/s/bosky-active-ow4qs7?file=/src/Components/Features/index.js

here is the header component:
https://codesandbox.io/s/bosky-active-ow4qs7?file=/src/Components/NavigationBar.js

I found a few similar StackOverflow post such as this one but their solution i already implemented so I am not sure what the issue is.

i could add padding on top of the 'features' element, then wrap it with another element and make the header anchor tag point to the parent element. but i don't think i want to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the feature component, put the margins in the col components instead of the row. It's related to the fixed navbar, the other elements must have a spacing top.

```
import { Row, Col, Image } from "react-bootstrap";

const Feature = () => {
  return (
    <Row id="features">
      <Col sm={7} className="px-4 my-5">
        <Image src="https://picsum.photos/900/400" fluid rounded className="" />
      </Col>
      <Col sm={5} className="px-4 my-5">
        <h1 className="font-weight-light">Use widget from website</h1>
        <p className="mt-4">
          Create dyanmic reports such as pie graphs, histographs
        </p>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
};

export default Feature;
```